# Pivot String SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to Pivot this table whose name is #salida

```
IDJOB NAME    DATE
1     Michael NULL
1     Aaron   NULl
```

THe result which I want to obtain is

```
IDJOB DATE NAME1    NAME2
1     NULL  Michael Aaron
```

My code is this

```
SELECT *
FROM #salida
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Name]) FOR [Name] IN ([Name1],[Name2])
) PVT GROUP BY IdJob,Date,Name1,Name2 ;

SELECT * FROM #salida
```

The result which obtain is

```
IDJOB DATE NAME1    NAME2
1     NULL  NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

@XabiIparra, see a mock up. you need to partition by the IdJob and then add the columns needed.

```
DECLARE @salida TABLE(idjob VARCHAR(100),[Name] VARCHAR(100),[DATE] DATE);
INSERT INTO @salida VALUES
 (1,'Michael', NULL)
,(1,'Aaron', NULL)
,(2,'Banabas', NULL)


SELECT p.*
FROM 
(
    SELECT * 
          ,'NAME'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [idjob] ORDER BY NAME) AS varchar(100)) ColumnName
    FROM @salida
)t
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Name]) FOR ColumnName IN (NAME1,NAME2,NAME3,NAME4,NAME5 /*add as many as you need*/)
)p;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about must using aggregation and `min()` and `max()`?

```
select idjob, date, min(name), max(name)
from #salida
group by idjob, date;
```

SQL tables represent unordered sets, so there is no ordering to the values (unless another column specifies the ordering).  So, this is probably the simplest way to get two different values in the same row.

Comment: should be `group by idjob, date`